# Why Hibernate always drops data in DB even if I use 'validate'?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, validation

I have Java Spring project, 
in application.properties file I have:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:/data/hsqldb/schema.sql
spring.datasource....
...
```

in data/hsqldb/schema.sql I have simple table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ToDoItem;
CREATE TABLE ToDoItem (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I start the application, create some data in ToDoItem table, but each time when I restart the application it deletes all data from this table. 
I want Hibernate just to validate table structure in DB and if it is OK - not touch the data.

By the way, I tried to comment out the *'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ToDoItem'* line, but in this case I get Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'todoitem' already exists

Answer (score 0):

You have written query to drop the table if already exists. Hence it is always deletes and creates the table again. So we don't need to drop if table already exist.

[This](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/Detectifatableexists.htm) may help how to check already table exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, each time you restart your application and if this file run every time then surely it will delete all data.

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ToDoItem;

you are dropping data first then creating it again

CREATE TABLE ToDoItem (

first check for table like:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SchemaName' 
                 AND  TABLE_NAME = 'TableName'))
BEGIN
    --some code
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   -- Create table code
END
```

if exists then validate otherwise create

Answer (score 0):

You seams to use MySql - in that case you can use `crete if not exists`, no drop neccessary:

```
CREATE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE ToDoItem (
  id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```